# How to Intercept Property Enumeration of an Object?

Tags: javascript

I need to intercept property enumeration of an object (of a certain class) when iterating with a for..in loop. All I need to know is whether the object has been accessed in a for..in loop or not.

```js
const myObject = new MyClass();
myObject["prop1"] = "val1";
myObject["prop2"] = "val2";
for (const p in myObject) {
    console.info(p + ": " + myObject[p]);
}
```

Expected output:

```
object enumerated
prop1: val1
prop2: val2
```

I do have full control over the class of the objects. It doesn't need to work with any object type.

This would be normally done using proxies. Unfortunately [the JS engine I am using has a bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-86323) that makes that impossible. Are there any other options? Maybe overriding the `getOwnPropertyNames()` method of `MyClass`?

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why exactly do you need to run code if an object is enumerated? The mechanics around this are implementation specific, so there isn't a generic way to programmatically influence it. Even proxies are of no use - at most, there is a trap for `in` and getting a property but that will fire on *every* access, not once when you access them in bulk.

Comment: No, I really need to know when the object is enumerated. I don't care whether I would get notified for every property access as well, that would be fine. The point is that the for..in loop might not access any of the properties. But I need to know about the attempt at least. This is part of a build automation system where user code (JS) iterates over (artifact) map objects and may or may not access some of the properties representing file artifacts. We need to track all kinds of accesses in order to create a fine-grained build graph.

Comment: @RichardW Then don't use objects. Use a `Map` or a custom class. Let them iterate the artifacts, not enumerate properties.

Comment: @Bergi yes, i would like to, but as I wrote in the question, there is a lot of existing user code that expects for..in to work unfortunately.

Comment: No, you haven't told us before that there is existing user code. Also, how does it currently work? Not at all? Then tell your users to rewrite their code if they want to make use of the new implicit dependency tracking feature.

Comment: Also, you should really consider switching to a different js engine, or fixing the bug in the engine yourself, if this is a real blocker. Or transpile all `for in` loops in your user code.

Comment: I am porting the Qbs build automation system from QtScript (based upon V8 engine) to QJSEngine (V4 engine) because QtScript has reached EOL. QtScript had a much richer C++ API to interact with JS objects. In QJSEngine I can work around this by using proxies. However, my JS knowledge is limited, so I was looking for alternative solutions to work around the mentioned bug in the engine. Looks like this bug is a real blocker then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there any other options?

No. Only a proxy can [trap the `for … in` enumeration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/ownKeys) itself.

Depending on your actual needs, you might be able to devise a hack with getters.

> Maybe overriding the `getOwnPropertyNames()` method of `MyClass`?

[`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) is a static method of `Object`, not a method of your class, and does not take part in a `for … in` loop.

Comment: I am already hacking getters for tracking actual property access, but I also need to know when the caller iterated over the object without accessing anything.

Comment: You really cannot do that without proxies.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I was afraid of a "no".